# MATLAB function doesn't work despite its script works fine

Tags: matlab, function

This function returns the error *Not enough input arguments*.

```css
function numgrad = computeNumericalGradient(J, theta)

SIZE=length(theta);
numgrad = zeros(SIZE,1);
perturb = zeros(SIZE,1);
e = 1e-4;
for p = 1:SIZE
    % Set perturbation vector
    perturb(p) = e;
    loss1 = J(theta - perturb);
    loss2 = J(theta + perturb);
    % Compute Numerical Gradient
    numgrad(p) = (loss2 - loss1) / (2*e);
    perturb(p) = 0;
end

end
```

When I pass J and theta as follows:

```css
function db = f(X)
db=X'*X;
end
```

```css
theta=[1; 2; 3];
```

However this script runs fine.

```css
theta=[1; 2; 3];

SIZE=length(theta);
numgrad = zeros(SIZE,1);
perturb = zeros(SIZE,1);
e = 1e-4;
for p = 1:SIZE
    % Set perturbation vector
    perturb(p) = e;
    loss1 = f(theta - perturb);
    loss2 = f(theta + perturb);
    % Compute Numerical Gradient
    numgrad(p) = (loss2 - loss1) / (2*e);
    perturb(p) = 0;
end
```

This is how I am calling my function.

```css
theta=[1; 2; 3];
computeNumericalGradien(f,theta)
```

I do not understand how does the script work given that the only difference in the script and function is that the function and its argument are not arbitrary in the script.

PS: I am using MATLAB 2014

Comment: What is your J input?

Comment: You haven't shown how you're calling your function when it throws the error. Or the full error...

Comment: function db = f(X)
db=X'*X;
end

Comment: You need to pass f as an anonymous function, you are calling it with no inputs, hence the error

Comment: @excaza I have edited my question to include the way I am calling my function.

Comment: You are simply passing a function to the function input , the function f itself requires an X input which is missing , better call the function f inside and pass X through the input

Comment: Unfortunately, you can't pass functions like that in MATLAB (use Python for that). If you really want to pass a function, use a function handle: `function_you_are_calling(@f,...`

Comment: @AndrasDeak Okay I shall see the documentation for function handle. Can you explain why am I getting *Not enough input arguments* error specifically?

Comment: Because in newer versions of MATLAB, writing `f` is equivalent to `f()`, which is a zero-input-argument form of a function.

Comment: Ok Thanks, if you wish to post it as an answer, I would accept it.

Comment: I think this is a simple typo problem, which is unlikely to help future readers. This is the reason I didn't give a full answer, only comment. I suggest that you consider deleting your question.

Comment: @AndrasDeak I don't agree. It highlights that saved/local functions are not passed as objects, which isn't particularly clear in the documentation. I think it's beneficial, though I wouldn't be surprised if there's a duplicate somewhere.